# Why Dismissible widget works differently under MaterialPageRoute?

Tags: flutter

I'm going through the Flutter's [Write your first app](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab) and I thought I'd add something extra to it. So I started playing around with `Dismissible` widget, similarly to how it's done in [cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible). But I noticed different behaviour of that widget when it's placed under `MaterialPageRoute`. The problem is that the `itemBuilder` index doesn't get updated once I dismiss the item, it will refer to the old position before any removals. Dismissing items from the main view does however update the index. Is anybody able to explain this behaviour?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Name Generator',
      home: RandomWords(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = generateWordPairs()
      .map((WordPair pair) => pair.asCamelCase)
      .take(10)
      .toList();
  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Startup Name Generator'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.list), onPressed: _pushSaved),
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildSuggestions(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemCount: _suggestions.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = _suggestions[index];
          return Dismissible(
              key: Key(item),
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                setState(() {
                  print("MaterialApp index: $index");
                  _suggestions.remove(item);
                });
              },
              background: Container(color: Colors.red),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  item,
                  style: _biggerFont,
                ),
              ));
        });
  }

  void _pushSaved() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Saved Suggestions'),
              ),
              body: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _suggestions.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final item = _suggestions[index];
                  return Dismissible(
                    key: Key(item),
                    onDismissed: (direction) {
                      setState(() {
                        print("MaterialPageRoute index: $index");
                        _suggestions.remove(item);
                      });
                    },
                    background: Container(color: Colors.red),
                    child: ListTile(title: Text('$item')),
                  );
                },
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RandomWordsState createState() => RandomWordsState();
}
```

Dismissing items from the main view, starting from the top, index reflects removals. After each dismiss, the top item has index 0:

```
I/flutter ( 8176): MaterialApp index: 0
I/flutter ( 8176): MaterialApp index: 0
I/flutter ( 8176): MaterialApp index: 0
```

Dismissing items from the MaterialPageRoute, starting from the top, index is preserved for all items. After each dismiss, the top item has its original index:

```
I/flutter ( 8176): MaterialPageRoute index: 0
I/flutter ( 8176): MaterialPageRoute index: 1
I/flutter ( 8176): MaterialPageRoute index: 2
```

Comment: accepting a helpful answer on stackoverflow signifies to future readers that it is helpful, it is also a sign of appreciation for the time the person spent solving your problem. And it is a way to earn some reputation points.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer (I don't have enough reputation to make that visible apparently), as the `setState` suggestion eventually pointed me in the right direction. However, I cannot accept it, as it's simply not an explanation of why I'm seeing different behaviour. Your workaround does work (for certain scenarios), but I was looking for a way where the index actually always reflects the actual state of the container.

Comment: I appreciate that @radszy, I just wanted to make your aware of this as a new member of the community, but obviously you understand them well enough, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The second `Route` doesn't get rebuilt after you dismiss items even though you explicitly call `setState()` inside `onDismiss()`, and items are correctly removed from `_saved`. Thus, the memory keeps the original `_suggestions` with its original length and item positions passed from main view. That's why although when you dismiss the first item (and it original index is 3) you get :

`MaterialPageRoute index: 3`

You can mimic the same behavior on the main screen by removing `setState` from its `Dismissible`.

Comment: I've updated the code in my question. I didn't intend to update `_saved`, but rather `_suggestions`, my bad. So, if you remove item from `_suggestions` in the `Route` you still get the same wrong behaviour.

Yes, I can get the same behaviour in the main screen, but that feels wrong. Imagine I want to call `_suggestions.removeAt(index)` - this will result in RangeError exception.

Comment: I corrected the mistake when I tested your code, but I also got the same result.

Comment: It won't won't cause any exception, because `removeAt()` returns `true` when the item in the list, otherwise `false`.see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/removeAt.html

Comment: Fine, imagine I want to access List by an index for whatever reason - `_suggestions[index]`, this will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

My question is apparently a duplicate of [setState not reloading state in Dart / Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845267/setstate-not-reloading-state-in-dart-flutter)

The reason for the different behaviour is that the `Route` is not a stateful widget. Wrapping it a `StatefulWidget` does solve the problem.